# Recessed lighting wiring questions

Tags: lighting, wire, recessed-lighting

I have installed (5) recessed lights to my ceiling. I just wanted to double check two questions.

1. Is my wiring sequence correct?

Switch to light #1 (**3** blacks, **3** whites, **3** grounds in #1),

light #1 to light #2 (**3** blacks, **3** whites, **3** grounds in #2),

.... and so on until,

light #4 to light #5 (**2** blacks, **2** whites, **2** grounds in light #5). The wires terminate at light #5.

2. I used the push connectors provided by the housing. If I cut the 12G wires' harness too long (about an inch) that when I inserted them into the push connector, some wire is still exposed at the base of the connector, can I just wrap electrical tape around the base of the connector with the wires? I know you can do this for a wire nut, but I haven't seen people do it with push connectors so I'm just making sure it's completely okay.

I know I can just remove the wire, cut it and reinsert but im afraid of loosening the push connector's grip by doing that.

Apologies for the noob questions. :)

Comment: You say you used 12 gauge wire on the push in connectors, in the US the outlets and switches are only listed for 14 gauge wire, there is usually a slot or hole next to the place the wire was pressed in to release the wire. Screw connectors are much more reliable I will only use push in connectors on Flouresents or led fixtures as they never draw much and I haven't had one fail there but when daisy changing fixtures regularly see failures from back stabs.

Comment: That is correct, push connectors are single use.  Either cut the wires the correct length the first time, or use wire nuts.  Frankly I recommend the latter, as push connectors make *point* contact with wires, whereas nuts make substantial contact, and this causes lots of flaky connections later. .  The key to nuts is use good ones (Ideal brand is electrician's choice) and tighten them plenty - if you stick the wires in straight,  the bare wires should tightly spiral inside the nut, and the insulated parts should start to also.  If not, twist more!

Comment: @ Ed Beal. My reading online was that I should be using 12G wire on 20A breakers? Since all my breakers at 20A, I went with the 12G. Is this incorrect in any way? Please advise.

Comment: @JamesL correct.  Backstabs on receptacles and switches are 14AWG only.  You are using a free floating push/stab connector, and those are often seen with multi-size rating, but you need to check the labeling and instructions for those specific push connectors.   Lighting circuits are often 15A and thus 14AWG is often the assumption.

Comment: @Harper Thanks for all your help. I think I will just cut the wires and join using correct-sized wire nuts since I have the exposed wire issue and for better contact. Thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to rend the wires out, you are not likely to damage the *wires* and will save some length.

Comment: @Harper Okay. I will try that first before cutting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cable colors are black white bare *simply because that is how cables are manufactured*, the colors do not reflect the functional purpose of each wire.

You may do wiring in either a **string** configuration or a **tree** configuration where unlimited branching is allowed.  (In fact a string is just a kind of tree configuration).  The tree layout means any number of cables can come together in a box.  So 3 cables at the switch and 3 cables at a light is not weird.  This is allowed:

```
               /-----------Lt1
 Supply -----SW                          /-----Lt3------------Lt5
               \                        /
                \--------------------Lt2-------------Lt4
```

However, are you including the cable *from the light itself* among the 3 wires/cables?  In that case you are simply doing the in-wall wiring in a string, and branching a very short branch out to the light itself.  That is fine and normal.   Counting the wires of the light itself, for instance in the above diagram, Lt2 would have 4 of each color wire.

You mentioned 3 cables at the switch.  I can only account for two:

- Supply (always-hot, neutral, and ground)
- Switched to the lamps (switched-hot, neutral and ground)

I cannot fathom what the third might be.  It might be a branched circuit to the lights (as in example above) or it may be

- onward supply to another point-of-use (always-hot, neutral, and ground).

This starts to get confusing, so I like to use colored tape.  For instance the conventional color of choice for *switched-hot* wires is red.  Always mark a wire on both ends at the same time, when you mark wire.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I believe by your explanation I went by the string configuration. 
Only 2 cables at the switch ->  
Supply (always hot, neutral, ground) and switched to lamps (switch hot, neutral, ground). There are 3 sets of cables (from switch or previous lamp, lamp itself, and out to next lamp) in the lamps,. Light #5 will just have 2 sets of cables from the previous lamp and the lamp itself.

Comment: @JamesL okay. That arrangement is pretty straightforward, then.

Comment: So I ran into an possible issue, the switch has 14G wires coming out of it. Would this be an issue if I connect 12G wires to it? My entire house is on 20A breakers. The switch used to power an outlet but Im switching it to power the lights.

Comment: If it is a switch eith screws or backstabs where you put the pigtails on it, then someone probably used #14 because #12 doesn't fit in backstabs.  If the switch is factory manufactured with pigtails, e.g. Smart switch, dimmer, switch/GFCI combo etc., then the smaller wire is allowed due to a special exception in Code, or rather, UL's product safety standards.

Comment: Gotcha. And have a 14G supply and 12G out tot he lamps isn’t a problem?